# Problem with the custom scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem in jquery in custom scroll bar. Here is the [source][1]

There is a custom scroll bar. It almost working fine, but the problem is, it doesn't go down to the last level. It just stops to a half way scroll.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: show us some **code** not a link to a website

Comment: just view source and save in an html file. code will become on your PC :)

Comment: this is not the way SO works. If you *want* help, post a question with all the elements needed. We are not paid to do things instead of you but we *can* help (and we do it for free).

Comment: but we don't need to check all your sourcecode to spot the bit which isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

Might have something to do with jQuery not being loaded

```
http://www.b52boutique.com/skin/frontend/base/default/js/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: what? http://www.b52boutique.com/js/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js doesn't seem 404 to me

Comment: Compare the URL you just linked to the URL that the page reported the error about, they are completely different URLs.

Comment: yes, thanks god i have eyes :) but the two declaration don't override each other, simply there's a jquery.js which is 404 and a jquery-1.3.2.min.js which is not 404... the "404" is not the issue (or basically the rest of the website won't work)

Comment: It might be worth fixing the raft of problems that dev tools immediately highlight before trying to fix the scroll problem.

Comment: Your page (http://www.b52boutique.com/whats_hot/) links to the script posted by Touk, not to -1.3.2.min.js - you need to give it a working copy of jQuery.